# getting build failed on running app on Xcode 13

Tags: iphone, xcode, react-native, cocoapods, ios-simulator

[image]

[image]

Getting following error on build and not able to run the app on Xcode. I have tried removing podfile and install it from the terminal(fresh) but still no improvement. The processing fails at build and displays error.

Comment: Please show the error messages as *text* instead of (or at least as well as) images, and please edit your title to avoid using all-caps, which is generally regarded as the equivalent to shouting.

Comment: Sorry Jon, changed the caps to lower case. I am using Xcode 13 version and i have displayed the error message in bottom of the image. Kindly have a look at that.

Comment: In case if it is m1 try running with Rosette.